# Cannot deserialize json string with NewtonSoft

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to desirialize the following Json string.

```
"{\"CPFs\":[{\"Numero\":\"13383857719\"},{\"Numero\":\"13383857720\"}]}"
```

I tried everything and I always get this error message:

> Error converting value
>   "{"CPFs":[{"Numero":"13383857719"},{"Numero":"13383857720"}]}" to type
>   'WebFFService.ListaCpf'. Path '', line 1, position 72.

I tried to use simple objects as List and even only CPF. But I always get the same output. I tried to use `JavaScripSerializer` either with no success.

```
// I've serialized a JSON as following:

var aux = new List<CPF>();

var cpf = new CPF {
  Numero = "13385860019"
};

var cpf2 = new CPF {
  Numero = "12283757720"
};

aux.Add(cpf);
aux.Add(cpf2);

var listaCpfs = new ListaCpf {
  CPFs = aux
};     

var jsonCpf = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listaCpfs);

// Where my classes are:    
public class ListaCpf
{
  public List<CPF> CPFs { get; set; }
}

public class CPF
{
  public string Numero { get; set; }
}

// And I'm trying to desirialize this way:        
var listaCpf = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ListaCpf>(jsonCpf);
```

I just want to put the numbers "Numeros" on a list or an Array.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: Have you tried https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-paste-json-as-classes-or-xml-as-classes-in-visual-stu/ ?

Comment: or have you tried http://json2csharp.com

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://rextester.com/NMB24655).

Comment: Share us a complete demo which could reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class ListaCpf
   {
       public CPF[] CPFs { get; set; }
   }

 public class CPF
  {
      public string Numero { get; set; }
  }


  { 
        var aux = new List<CPF>();

        var cpf = new CPF
        {
            Numero = "13385860019"
        };

        var cpf2 = new CPF
        {
            Numero = "12283757720"
        };

        aux.Add(cpf);
        aux.Add(cpf2);

        var listaCpfs = new ListaCpf
        {
            CPFs = aux.ToArray()
          };

           var jsonCpf = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listaCpfs);
```

// Where my classes are:

```
    // And I'm trying to desirialize this way:        
          var listaCpf = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ListaCpf>(jsonCpf);
          }
```